# GWT + DynamicJasper

Tags: gwt

Have anyone tried DynamicJasper + gwt before?

I plan to use it but now I facing problem on compile the same project in my local PC

http://dynamicjasper.sourceforge.net/docs/project-setup.html

I am following the above steps.

*The only different is I didnt use MAven at all
*My gwt is 1.7.0 and java is latest version

Answer (score 0):

I did. But you need to be specific about what your issue is about GWT and DynamicJasper.

Just a tip: 
In order for DynamicJasper to work, you will have to write a separate Servlet to write to the output stream.